# MongoDB fulltext search: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, full-text-search, text-search

I am trying to implement mongo text search in my node(express.js) application.

Here are my codes:

```
Collection.find({$text: {$search: searchString}}
, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}})
.sort({score: {$meta: 'textScore'}})
.exec(function(err, docs {

//Process docs
});
```

I am getting following error when text search is performed on large dataset:

> MongoError: Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554558 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes

I am aware that MongoDB can sort maximum of 32MB data and this error can be avoided by adding index for field we will be sorting collection with. But in my case I am sorting collection by `textScore` and I am not exactly sure if is it possible to set index for this field. If not, is there any workaround for this?

**NOTE:** I am aware there are similar questions on SO but most of these questions do not have `textScore` as sort criteria and therefore  my question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate to circumvent the limit.

```
Collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { $text: { $search: searchString } } },
    { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }
])
```

The `$sort` stage has a 100 MB limit. If you need more, you can use `allowDiskUse`, that will write to temp files while sorting takes place. To do that just add `allowDiskUse: true` to the aggregate option.

If your result is greater than 16MB (i.e. MongoDB's document size limit), you need to request a cursor to iterate through your data. Just add `.cursor()` before your exec and here's a detailed example. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-cursor

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried passing `allowDiskUse` option with aggregate function but I am getting following error if there are many search results which was expected: "aggregate failed: {
  "errmsg": "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",
  "code": 16389,
  "ok": 0
}"

Comment: Ignore that. Apparently, your result is greater than 16MB now. Updating my original answer to fix it.

Comment: Yes result of aggregate query is greater than 16MB.

Comment: `cursor` works but using cursor won't be best approach in my case. I'll see if I can figure out something that works with `find`.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I had to go with `cursor`. Thank you for the solution. I was stuck since past 7 days.